# Is it possible to use io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda and io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-jib together?

Tags: gradle, quarkus

I'm having a build setup for quarkus (version `3.4.3`) with gradle (wrapper version `8.2.1`). My application solves an optimization problem (VRP) using Optaplanner and thus may take quite a while to run, depending on the input dataset.

Since basically all of our other backends are using AWS Lambda, we also started out with lambda knowing we can later move from cloud functions to a containerized version (on e.g. Fargate) in case we need our solver to run longer than Lambdas maximum runtime of 15 minutes.

To achieve this, I've now added `implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-jib'` to my dependencies and the existing `implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda'` is still there, because we want to still be able to delegate tasks for simpler datasets to Lambda. However, when running `./gradlew build -Dquarkus.container-image.build=true`, I encounter following error:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: [...]/build/quarkus-run.jar
```

I've tried to remove `quarkus-amazon-lambda` from the dependencies, which got the container build working as expected. It seems using this dependency doesn't result in the `build` command creating the `quarkus-run.jar` anymore.

Since I couldn't find more detailed information in the documentation for the quarkus lambda extension, I have the following question:

Is it possible to get these two ways of packaging the application working together in the same gradle project or do I need to try something different like splitting the single project into a multi-project setup? If the latter is the case, are there other options than a multi-project setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can write separate run tasks.

###### Use separate configurations

First, change the dependency declaration to put them in different configurations, so you can pick them up separately (using Groovy DSL):

```
configurations {
    awsLambda
    container
}

dependencies {
    def quarkusVersion = "3.4.3"
    awsLambda "io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda:$quarkusVersion"
    container "io.quarkus:quarkus-container-image-jib:$quarkusVersion"
}
```

###### Using dependencies in main code

No doubt you need to refer to classes from Quarkus as well in your code, which you won't be able to based on the above. Assuming either library can serve for this purpose (which is implied by your question), you can place one of the dependencies in the `compileOnly` configuration so the compilation can see it, but so that it is not present at runtime unless it is specifically added (as it is in the `implementation` configuration).

```
configurations {
    // continued from above
    compileOnly.extendsFrom awsLambda
}
```

###### Writing run tasks

Then write some run tasks, one for each Quarkus dependency, sharing as much configuration as possible by writing a function:

```
registerExecTask("runAwsLambda", "awsLambda") { /* unique configuration */ }
registerExecTask("runContainer", "container")

def registerExecTask(String name, String configurationName, Action<JavaExec> otherConfig = {}) {
    tasks.register(name, JavaExec.class) {
        classpath(java.sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath, configurations[configurationName])
        mainClass.set("grey.haired.bear.optimization.main") // assuming same entry point
        workingDir(layout.projectDirectory)
        otherConfig.execute(it)
    }
}
```

Then you can run the respective tasks to execute whichever setup you want, with the classpath never containing both Quarkus dependencies.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late comment. I'm not quite sure that this will work out and I think that I would prefer multi-project setup over this solution. Seems a bit less complicated and less error prone way of juggling with dependencies - but that might just be my subjective view and experience.

Comment: Certainly a multi-project approach is possible, so you can write according to your taste. Yet you asked for a single project approach, so I provided one :)